# AVPlayer won't resume playing after being paused

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudiosession, nsnotifications

I just switched from `AVAudioPlayer` to `AVPlayer` and I'm going through my old functions and making the appropriate adjustments.  The `AVPlayer` is being used to play remote audio files using URL's.  When I select a file to play and pause everything works perfectly.  However, when I want to resume playing the paused file, the player won't play even though I see the play function is being called.  I set up an observer to know when the player is done playing so the play/pause button can toggle and what I noticed is that the observer is getting called after I hit pause.  This shouldn't happen since the player isn't done playing right? Anyways, I set breakpoints and everything is getting called correctly.  Any idea why the `AVPlayer` won't resume playing after being paused?

```
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var newPlayer: AVPlayer?
var trackIDplaying: Int?

func playPausePressed(_ sender:UIButton) 
{

    if let selectedTrackID = trackIDplaying
    {

         do 
         {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            if selectedTrackID == track.trackId
            {
                //if playing, then pause.  If not playing, then play
                if (self.newPlayer!.rate != 0)
                {
                    self.newPlayer!.pause()
                    self.isPaused = true   
                }
                else
                {
                    if self.newPlayer!.currentItem != nil
                    {
                        self.newPlayer!.play()
                        print(self.newPlayer!.currentItem)
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //If song is playing, switch to new song
                let trackURL = URL(string: track.preSignedURL!)
                trackIDplaying = track.trackId
                self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: trackURL!)
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector((HomeController.playerDidFinishPlaying)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerItem)
                self.newPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
                self.newPlayer!.play()
            }
         }
         catch let error1 as NSError 
         {
            error = error1
            self.newPlayer = nil
         }
    }
    else 
    {
         do 
         {
             //play selected song if no other songs are playing
            let trackURL = URL(string: track.preSignedURL!)
            print(trackURL!)
            self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: trackURL!)
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector((HomeController.playerDidFinishPlaying)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerItem)

            self.newPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
            self.newPlayer!.play()
            self.trackIDplaying = track.trackId
         }
    }
    if let err = error 
    {
         print("audio player error \(err.localizedDescription)", terminator: "")
    }
}

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {

    guard let indexPath = self.playingAudioIndexPath, let cell = self.audioTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AudioCell else {

        return;
    }

    cell.playButton.isSelected = false
    self.playingAudioIndexPath = nil

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding observer in only `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()` adding observer should only done in one time for these kind of problems.
Still you have any problem feel free to ask me.

Comment: by declaring the observer when I hit play, why was it automatically jumping to the observer method when toggling pause/play.

Comment: It worked, just wondering why the original way I was doing it wasn't working.

Comment: yes. As I told you.. AddObserver Method() Will start observing once we call it. In another function. It overrides so, Sometimes it couldn't find the exect removal. If the answer helps you please up vote it...